# I recently installed Ubuntu 14.04 and have trouble with Wi-Fi

Tags: wireless, networking

This is the output of the wireless script that has been requested by the admin. My Wi-fi network is detected by other devices but not on the one in which I have installed Ubuntu.

The wireless script output is available here : http://pastebin.ubuntu.com/8539562/

Edit1: Result of `rfkill list all`

```
0: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

Edit2:

```
[    1.028956] Loaded X.509 cert 'Magrathea: Glacier signing key: 6c4cccd23ec578fee9b9e0c7e2670c91f2e0a0ac'
[   14.276655] ath: phy0: Enable LNA combining
[   14.386589] ath: EEPROM regdomain: 0x69
[   14.386590] ath: EEPROM indicates we should expect a direct regpair map
[   14.386591] ath: Country alpha2 being used: 00
[   14.386592] ath: Regpair used: 0x69
[   17.062635] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlan0: link is not ready
[   17.063314] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlan0: link is not ready
```

Comment: Is there a wireless switch? Please note: "Hard blocked: yes"

Comment: @chili555 I have tried the wifi connectivity with the hardswitch ON. Had to execute the script on hardswitch off since I was using the LAN connection

Comment: What is the result if you detach the ethernet, move the switch and then run: rfkill list all? Is it still hard blocked?

Comment: Have edited the question with the result.

Comment: Now does the interface scan? sudo iwlist wlan0 scan? Does it try and fail to connect? Any clues in the log? dmesg | grep -e wlan -e ath

Comment: @chili555 have updated the logs in the question.

Comment: @devGeek What is a Broadcom driver going to do to help his Atheros card? Waste time??

Comment: Does it scan? Does it try to connect at all?

Comment: It scans and shows every Wi-Fi in my vicinity except mine.

Comment: Is your router set to 802.11N speeds? I doubt that your ath9k is so capable. Is the SSID hidden? Please try with it unhidden. Is this correct for your region domain: "Region: Asia/Kolkata (based on set time zone)" What channel is the router set on? Based on the region code, the card will only use channels 1-11.

Comment: @chili555 That solved it !! Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Your ath9k card may respond better to a fixed channel from 1 to 11 rather than channel:auto.

Comment: @guntbert If you read the comments on the question, this actually solved the problem :)

Answer (score 0):

This was an issue due to wi-fi configuration. The Router was set to channel:auto however changing it to channel 11 solved the issue.